# How can I programatically obtain a servlet filter instance?

Tags: servlet-filters, tomcat8

I have a class `MyFilter` which implements `javax.servlet.Filter`.  Tomcat creates a single instance of this based on the `web.xml` configuration.  The filter collects statistics about all requests (since application start) and stores them in member variables.

I wish to display these statistics on a web page.  How can I obtain the instance of `MyFilter` which was created by Tomcat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html):

> Every Filter has access to a FilterConfig object from which it can
> obtain its initialization parameters, a reference to the
> ServletContext which it can use.

Why do not you store the data you need in ServletContext attributes? You can store the filter as follows:

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException
{
    // Store our instance in the servlet context for usage by servlets.
    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
    context.setAttribute("MyFilter", this);
}
```

And then in the servlet with the same context:

```
Filter filter = (Filter) getServletContext().getAttribute("MyFilter");
```

Comment: The `FilterRegistration` unfortunately does not have the instance of the filter, only the filter name, class name and configuration.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that. Then you may consider my first suggesstion.